# What directories does user own - LTS 12.04

Tags: 12.04, files, sudo, users, tty

Which directories in the hierarchy does the default main user (UID 1000) own? like maybe `/usr/share/` or `/bin/` 
I need to now exactly the directories my user needs to own in the hierarchy, in short I made a mistake, details here:

[12.04 LTS won't boot after modifying root directory permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211940/12-04-lts-wont-boot-after-modifying-root-directory-permissions/211951#comment263063_211951)

And specifically which files handle the `sudo` command, as when I try to use it from tty it reports an error, `sudo: need to be root to perform operation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CD to the directory you want to search and use the `find` program:

```
find -uid 1000
```

You can find out any user ID with `id`:

```
id <username>
```

On my system (12.04) the sudo program is at `/usr/bin/sudo` and has the "Set UID" bit (permissions `-rwsr-xr-x`). This command might fix it, if you run it as root:

```
 chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Every user should own just their home directory, with everything else being owned by root. One exception is files inside `/tmp`, which are owned by the user that created them. However, `/tmp` itself is owned by root, but is writable by anyone (permissions 777).

The other exception is files inside `/proc`, but the contents of this directory are created by the kernel and you don't need to alter the permissions of anything inside.

To fix permissions, boot into recovery mode, CD to `/`, and run:

```
chown root:root -R *
```

Then CD to `/home` and fix each home directory:

```
 chown <user>:<user> -R <home_dir>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `find` script, bring up the files owned by UID 1000??
Well, I changed that; `sudo chown -hR jmayerz:jmayerz /` was the command I accidentally typed. What I need to know is what files in the hierarchy does the user own by default so I can change ownership of everything else to `root` except for these. Could you find that out for me on your own system?

Comment: Basically, I just own my home folder. Check out my updated answer above.